# Trouble Deploying Spring Boot/Gradle WAR to Eclipse Tomcat 8 Server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, gradle, spring-boot

So deploying my WAR initially would look to be successful but when trying to access localhost:8282/thymeleaf-test or localhost:8282/thymeleaf-test/myapp gives me a 404 error.

Finding the Spring Boot reference guide online I changed my application.java class

From:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

 }
}
```

To:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
}
```

Changing only this I now keep running into the following stacktrace error when I attempt to deploy:

```
java.lang.ClassCircularityError: java/util/logging/LogRecord
org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getSLF4JLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:198)
org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:293)
java.util.logging.Logger.log(Unknown Source)
java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Unknown Source)
java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Unknown Source)
org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:182)
org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.error(DirectJDKLog.java:148)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:76)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:934)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:515)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1012)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:642)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1555)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea at all why this might be happening?

My gradle.build file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

buildscript {
    ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.4.0.M1'
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://maven:8081/nexus/content/groups/EADSSExternal/' }
    maven { url 'http://maven:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE")
 }
}

war {
baseName = 'thymeleaf-test'
//version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
maven { url "http://maven:8081/nexus/content/groups/EADSSExternal/" }
maven { url 'http://maven:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/' }
}

configurations {
     providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: "$springBootVersion" 
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging', version: "$springBootVersion"
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: "$springBootVersion"
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: "$springBootVersion"
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: "$springBootVersion"

providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: "$springBootVersion"
providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'

compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap', version: '3.3.6'
compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'jquery', version: '2.2.4'

testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: "$springBootVersion"
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: "4.8.2"

}

eclipse {
classpath {

 }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

My application.properties file:

```
server.port=8282
server.context-path=/myapp
```

Comment: What is success link? `http://localhost:8282/` ?

Comment: That just brings me to the Tomcat front page.